# No Sound after installing Ubuntu 12 along side Windows 8

Tags: installation, sound

I am a total new comer to Ubuntu. I got a LiveCD from Ubuntu.com and did the install. Installed Windows 8 on one partition and Ubuntu on another.

After the install, everything is great and I am enjoying the OS, except when I play a YouTube video, I get no sound. Now I realize I am not getting any sound from either Ubuntu or Windows 8.

Please help me.

Comment: When you have the same problem in two complete different OSes, using total different drivers, it's usually a clear symptom of a hardware problem.

Comment: the problem with windows doesn't relate to the problem you having with Ubuntu and vise versa. windows needs some drivers, try finding them in your manufacturer website, however the problem with Ubuntu might be that you are using 3.2 kernel (i.e. 12.04 or 12.04.1). you can upgrade to 12.10 or 12.04.2. I can point you to lots of tweaks but for me non of them worked. and also you probably have sound in your headphones when plugged in.

Comment: Thanks guys. I will update and see. The reason why I attributed it to the Ubuntu install is that before the install my sound was working fine for Windows 8. After the install, I checked all the devices in Windows and non of them seem to have any problems.

Comment: I installed the update, but it turns out only Ubuntu now gets sound. No sound for Windows 8, even though the hardware reports to be working correctly. Any help, please?

Answer (score 0):

Ok. This was a false alarm. It turns out that the Beats Audio software on my computer was not working in Ubuntu since there is no Ubuntu version. Hence, when I updated Ubuntu, the local sound card activated and was able to provide me with sound.

As for Windows, the Beats Audio software was installed, but not running and since it controls the sound, the sound card reported to work properly, but there was no sound.

**Solution to this problem:** If you installed Ubuntu and you don't get sound, *"the problem with Ubuntu might be that you are using 3.2 kernel (i.e. 12.04 or 12.04.1). You can upgrade to 12.10 or 12.04.2."* as Soroosh129 pointed out above.

For Windows, check to see whether there is a third party application that controls your sound (in my case, it is Beats Audio), and configure it properly.

Thanks to you all for helping out.